# Is it possible to add an item to a List contained in a Stream in Dart?

Tags: dart, stream

**Problem**

I have a `Stream<List>` which is being listened to in several classes and I need all the classes to receive the updated stream once a value is added to the list in the Stream.

**What I have tried**

```
void main() {
  StreamedList<String> dataStream = StreamedList();

  dataStream.data.listen((list) => print(list));

  dataStream.updateList(['Apple', 'Orange']);
  dataStream.addToList('Mango');       // This is what I want to do
}
```

This is the code for `StreamList` class

```
class StreamedList<T> {
  StreamController<List<T>> _controller = StreamController.broadcast();

  Stream<List<T>> get data => _controller.stream;

  void updateList(List<T> list) {
    _controller.sink.add(list);
  }

  void addToList(T value) {
    // Is it possible to do this?
    // List<T> dataList = await _controller.data;
    // dataList.add(value);
    // updateList(dataList);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _controller.close();
  }
}
```

I have tried different APIs from the `dart:async` library including `Stream.first`, etc. which return a `Future<List<T>>`. But the problem is that this Future resolves only after something is added to the Stream later (eg. by calling the `StreamedList.updateList` function).

**Question**

How do I add a single value to the `List` inside the `Stream`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what a `Stream` does. It doesn't "contain" data. It merely accepts data on one end (the sink) and propagates it out the other end (the stream), and any listeners gain access to the streamed object. Trying to "insert an item in a list within the stream" doesn't make any conceptual sense.

If you want to push a list with an additional item, take the old list, append the item to it, then re-add the list to the stream.

```dart
class StreamedList<T> {
  StreamController<List<T>> _controller = StreamController.broadcast();

  Stream<List<T>> get data => _controller.stream;

  List<T> _list = [];

  void updateList(List<T> list) {
    _list = list;
    _dispatch();
  }

  void addToList(T value) {
    _list.add(value);
    _dispatch();
  }

  void _dispatch() {
    controller.sink.add(_list);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _list = null;
    _controller.close();
  }
}
```

If you wanted to be doubly safe, you could recreate the list after every `addToList`, since if a listener captured the list elsewhere and modified its contents, that would affect `_list` as well.

```dart
void addToList(T value) {
  _list = [..._list, value];
  _dispatch();
}
```